# How to read and rbind all .xlsx files in a folder efficiently using read_excel

Tags: r, xlsx, rbind

I am new to R and need to create one dataframe from 80 .xlsx files that mostly share the same columns and are all in the same folder. I want to bind all these files efficiently in a manner that would work if I added or removed files from the folder later. I want to do this without converting the files to .csv, unless someone can show me how to that efficiently for large numbers of files within R itself.

I've previously been reading files individually using the `read_excel` function from the readxl package. After, I would use `rbind` to bind them. This was fine for 10 files, but not 80! I've experimented with many solutions offered online however none of these seem to work, largely because they are using functions other than `read_excel` or formats other than .xlsx. I haven't kept track of many of my failed attempts, so cannot offer code other than one alternate method I tried to adapt to `read_excel` from the `read_csv` function.

```
#Method 1
library(readxl)
library(purr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
alldata <- file.list %>%
map(read_excel) %>%
reduce(rbind)

#Output
New names:
* `` -> ...2
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

Any code on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if anything is wrong about this post, it is my first one.

UPDATE:
Using the changes suggested by the answers, I'm now using the code:

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
alldata <- file.list %>%
map_dfr(read_excel) %>%
reduce(bind_rows)
```

This output now is as follows:

```
New names:
* `` -> ...2
Error: Column `10.Alert.alone` can't be converted from numeric to character
```

This happens regardless of which type of `bind()` function I use in the `reduce()` slot.  If anyone can help with this, please let me know!

Comment: Your error message points out that the columns in the excels do not match, is this an error or true? If so use ```bind_rows()``` from ```dplyr``` to add rows even if columns do not match,

Comment: @Fnguyen I believe some of the older files may be missing two columns. At what point would I need to use 'bind_rows' to do that whilst opening all the files, etc? Just in place of wherever I'd use rbind above?

Comment: Yes essentially ```bind_rows()``` replaces ```rbind``` one for one but differs in behavior. Namely it just adds different columns and fills in NA if the column is missing for a row.

Comment: @Fnguyen thank you for your explanation! Unfortunately, now I receive the following error: `Error: Column X can't be converted from numeric to character`, despite the columns being identical. This happens whether I use `bind_rows` , `rbind_list`, or `rbind.fill` in the `reduce()` function. The `error in rbind(disperse.level,...)` error is gone, though, so thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track here. But you need to use `map_dfr` instead of plain-vanilla `map`. `map_dfr` outputs a data frame (or actually tibble) for each iteration, and combines them via `bind_rows`.

This should work:

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
alldata <- file.list %>%
  map_dfr(~read_excel(.x))
```

Note that this assumes your files all have consistent column names and data types. If they don't, you may have to do some cleaning. (One trick I've used in complex cases is to add a `%>% mutate_all(as.character)` to the `read_excel` command inside the map function. That will turn *everything* into characters, and then you can convert the data types from there.)

Comment: This appears really hopeful, however I get the below error:

`Error: Column 10.Alert.alone can't be converted from numeric to character`

I don't know why as it's identical to the other columns! Any idea why this may be the case?

Comment: If you aren't specifying column types, read_excel is probably guessing wrong on one of your .xlsx files. Try either specifying the types or converting all the columns to as.character() from within the map_dfr function (and then you can convert from there).

Answer (score 0):

this should get you there/close...

```
library(data.table)
library(readxl)
#create files list
file.list <- list.files( pattern = ".*\\.xlsx$", full.names = TRUE )
#read files to list of data.frames
l <- lapply( l, readxl::read_excel )
#bind l together to one larger data.table, by columnname, fill missing with NA 
dt <- data.table::rbindlist( l, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using map_dfr.

```
alldata <- file.list %>%
map_dfr(read_excel)
```